# Stripping <style> and <link> tags from value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to clean up some HTML values that are imported from other sources, primarily email message bodies. Ideally, I would like to be able to strip `<style>` and `<link>` tags, but also apply their styles (assuming the link tag points to a style sheet) to the appropriate elements within the value.

I am currently trying to accomplish this via [tidy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php). If it comes down to it, I can strip out the tags without applying the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use php's [simple-xml functions](http://php.net/simplexml) to assign the styles to your markup.

or write some custom implementation to manipulate the html (which is not a good practice tbh) if you don't want to get into the simplexml lib.

```
$dirtyInput = '<!-- your html string -->';

$regex = '/<style[^>]>(.*?)</style>/is';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $dirtyInput, $inlineStyles)) {

    // your inline styles will be in $inlineStyles
    $cleanedOutput = preg_replace($regex . 'g', '', $dirtyInput );
}


$regex = '/<link[^>]*href="([^"]+)"*[^>]*>/is';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $dirtyInput, $externalFiles)) {

    // hrefs of external stylesheets $externalFiles;
    $cleanedOutput = preg_replace($regex . 'g', '', $cleanedOutput);
}

// more code to read styles from external css files and apply their styles and the inline styles to your markup (not a quick task...)
```

Comment: hmm... I did not think about using SimpleXML. Perhaps I will give this a try.

Comment: have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I got pulled off on to another project. I have been thinking about this though and it seems feasible, just haven't had time to figure out how I'm going to parse the CSS and search for the proper elements (using xpath obviously).